# Error: Cannot resolve type entity i29.DragAndDropModule to symbol

Tags: angular, webpack, upgrade, ivy

After upgrading from Angular 15 to 16 getting the same error for ./src/main.ts and ./src/polyfills.ts Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Cannot resolve type entity i29.DragAndDropModule to symbol.

Solution contains the setting "preserveSymlinks": true

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx-web",
  "version": "0.0.312",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electon.xxxxx-Web",
    "main": "main.js",
    "productName": "xxxxx-Web",
    "files": [
      "main.js",
      "dist/xxxxx-web"
    ],
    "win": {
      "icon": "./img/icon.ico",
      "target": "msi"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prebuild": "npm --no-git-tag-version version patch",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build --configuration production --base-href ./ && electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . xxxxx-web --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=src/assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"xxxxx-Web\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . xxxxx-web --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-lin-arm71": "electron-packager . xxxxx-web --overwrite --platform=linux --arch=armv7l --icon=src/assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-lin-arm64": "electron-packager . xxxxx-web --overwrite --platform=linux --arch=arm64 --icon=src/assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/material-luxon-adapter": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.4",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.5",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-barcodes": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-gauges": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-indicators": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-listview": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pager": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-sortable": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^12.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-date-math": "^1.5.11",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.17.5",
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-recurrence": "^1.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^6.4.0",
    "angular-user-idle": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "d3": "^7.8.5",
    "d3-org-chart": "^2.7.0",
    "electron": "^25.0.1",
    "electron-packager": "^17.1.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "mammoth": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-image-fullscreen-view": "^3.0.3",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.9.2",
    "ng-qrcode": "^16.0.0",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "^15.0.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^6.3.4",
    "ngx-otp-input": "^0.11.4",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.4.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "^12.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "powerbi-client-angular": "^3.0.5",
    "powerbi-report-authoring": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/d3-org-chart": "^2.6.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "yarn-upgrade-all": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

Upgraded from Angular 15 to 16 with unexpected errors.

Answer (score 8):

Some of your imported kendo packages need kendo utils.
This should fix it:

- `npm i @progress/kendo-angular-utils --save`
- `npm i @progress/kendo-angular-navigation --save`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, solved the issue

Comment: +1. `npm install` also shows these missing dependencies, so the issue can be detected earlier than runtime.